# How do I specify that the return type will be the same as the input type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I have a function below where `target` can be any type. I want to type this function so that the output `T` is the same as whatever type is passed in as `target`.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def lowercase_if_possible(target: Type[T]) -> T:
    if isinstance(target, str):
        return target.lower()
    return target
```

I assume this has something to do with generics but I can't figure out the syntax as the Python docs only show generics used on classes, not an individual function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type[T]` indicates that the value of `target` is a class (or subclass) itself, rather than a value of the type. For example,

```
def instantiate(c: Type[T]) -> T:
    return c()

instantiate(int)  # Returns 0, a value of type int
instantiate(str)  # Returns "", a value of type str
```

`T` alone is all you need. Given a value of type `T`, you'll return a value of type `T`, regardless of what that type is.

```
def lowercase_if_possible(target: T) -> T:
    if isinstance(target, str):
        return target.lower()
    return target
```

(Note that without a runtime check to determine what `T` actually is, the *only* think you can do is return the given value, because you don't know enough about the value to actually do anything *with* it.)

Generics are for defining a class that *wraps* an arbitrary but definite type.

Answer (score 1):

You're close to the right solution, simply use `T` as the type for `target` and it should do the trick.